# Waveform API from Apple commercial?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, audio, avaudioplayer

In the new iPhone 3GS commercial, Apple shows voice control with a cool blue waveform animation. Is this visual effect for rendering the waveforms (or maybe just volumes) available as an API call or source code somewhere? (Not the voice control part, just the audio visualization)

I think you could get the sound info from AVAudioPlayer's averagePowerForChannel: method, but how would you show the waves moving up and down?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you link to an online version of the commercial?

Comment: http://www.apple.com/iphone/iphone-3gs/voice-control.html#video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John,

That code that you found for drawing the sine wave is great. [This sample code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) shows a sound meter with live audio recording. With those two resources, you should be on track to make the visual waveform.

Answer (score 1):

The waveform in the apple commercials is very clearly just a plain old sine wave that looks like it's got its amplitude modulated by the volume of the input.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I also found some sine wave code here - http://trailsinthesand.com/plotting-a-sine-wave-with-the-iphone-sdk/